# Using for update with bulk collect pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, locking

I have function in which I have to add **for update** clause.

```
    FUNCTION FUNC_NAME(
    strValues IN arrayofstrings)
    RETURN arrayofnumbers IS
    ids arrayofnumbers := arrayofnumbers();
BEGIN
    SELECT myId BULK COLLECT INTO ids
    FROM table_1
    WHERE table_1.rownum1 IN (select column_value from table(strValues))
    GROUP BY myId
    HAVING count(*) = (select count(*) from table(strValues))
    --for update of myId
    ;
    RETURN ids;
END FUNC_NAME;
```

but if delete comment, the error

```
Error(26,7): PL/SQL: ORA-01786: FOR UPDATE of this query expression is not allowed
```

how can I rebuild my query?

Comment: It is a syntax error - it should be `for update OF myId`.

Comment: @TonyAndrews, yes, I missed 'OF' in example

Comment: @Nikolas. The question here why do you want to do it that way. What is your requirement. You cannot use that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply locked rows from a table using `for update` where you are using `group by` clause. A `group by` clause will give a wholistic view of table data by grouping the records on the specified columns hence it doesnot make sense as well,if you lock rows for any DML. You can use as below and lock rows.

**Either:**

Here in example i use an Oracle inbuilt collection `sys.odcinumberlist`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNC_NAME (strValues IN SYS.odcinumberlist)
   RETURN SYS.odcinumberlist
IS
   ids   SYS.odcinumberlist;

   CURSOR fall_jobs_cur (strValues IN SYS.odcinumberlist)
   IS
          SELECT myId
            FROM table_1
           WHERE table_1.rownum1 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
                                       FROM TABLE (strValues))
      FOR UPDATE OF myId;
BEGIN
   OPEN fall_jobs_cur (strValues);

   FETCH fall_jobs_cur BULK COLLECT INTO ids;

   RETURN ids;
END FUNC_NAME;
```

**Or**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNC_NAME (strValues IN SYS.odcinumberlist)
   RETURN SYS.odcinumberlist
IS
   ids   SYS.odcinumberlist;
BEGIN
       SELECT myId
         BULK COLLECT INTO ids
         FROM table_1
        WHERE table_1.rownum1 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
                                    FROM TABLE (strValues));
      FOR UPDATE OF myId;

   RETURN ids;
END FUNC_NAME;
```

The above two codes will compile but when you will execute it, you will again face issue.

**Like :**

```
SQL> SELECT FUNC_NAME(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3)) col1 from dual;
SELECT FUNC_NAME(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3)) col1 from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query
ORA-06512: at "FUNC_NAME", line 8
ORA-06512: at "FUNC_NAME", line 14
```

So my question is what do you really wanted to achieve.

Comment: I want to block table table_1 from asynchronous queries

Comment: Second variant is ok) Thanks